# Тотальная ненависть? Множественные минусы на ответах от неизвестных

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, голоса-против

Я как бы не кармад**чер, но все таки обидно. Сидел себе, смотрел видео, а затем решил проверить стаковерфлоу, после обновления рейтинг вдруг резко упал с 848 до 788 пунктов. И что же я увидел? Некий хейтер (или группа) забрали у меня 56 баллов, заминусовав 28 мои ответов, как не трудно догодаться. До этого я получал минусы и вполне оправдано, тут я даже спорить не буду, но вот так, изподтишка, сразу скопом... На сколько такое поведение оправдано и стоит ли вообще "жаловаться"? Тут варианта 2: либо у меня завелся реальный хейтер (я что, популярным, блин, стал? это вряд ли), либо кто-то занимается этим от нечего делать, и тогда любой из участников подвергнется таким же атакам в будущем. Либо (!) Дух Сообщества посчитал что мой рейтинг незаслужено заработан. Скриншоты прилагаю...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Минусование массовое, а потому голоса будут автоматически аннулированы в полночь по Гринвичу.

Comment: короч, смысл в том, что беспокоиться не стоит. Массовые минусы откатятся системой (если конечно кто-то не заморочился и не насоздавал кучу клонов :))

Comment: Надо дубликат найти, не могу никак этого сделать

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но: знает ли система о таких набегах или нужно "жаловаться" каждый раз? И если дубликат, я могу удалить вопрос, без проблем

Comment: Система отслеживает подобное сама. Возможно, даже «стучит» модераторам постфактум (чтобы те провели воспитательную беседу с нарушителем либо отправили его в бан «за нарушения при голосовании»).

Comment: @DaemonHK система видит. Но обычно это если >3 ответов было  заминусовано. Если меньше или равно 3, то возможно это просто кто-то действительно решил, что вопросы-ответы не очень надлежащего качества..... Поэтому если вдруг происходят именно *массовые* минуса и через сутки отката не было - то можно уже обратиться в общий чат или менеджеру сообщества

Comment: С другой стороны, подобные вопросы будут периодически всплывать, поэтому может подобная ситуация описана в справке? Мол, парни, не волнуйтесь, все откатится.

Comment: @DaemonHK https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: Спасибо большое всем ответившим)) если будет возможно, то данный вопрос будет удален

Comment: @DaemonHK, удалять не нужно) Дубликат != ненужный вопрос. Чем больше формулировок тем вероятнее, что больше дубликатов не будет, ибо следующие задающие подобный вопрос увидят один из дубликатов и найдут там ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хорошо, больше не буду))